# How to end process based on window title bar?

Tags: api, vb6

The following vb6 code, can show (title bar of (active window)):

Is there a way **to find the exe file name of the active window** to end process of it?

Please look at the last line (example) in the following code:

```
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim ActiveWindowHandle As Long

    ActiveWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow()

    Dim Title As String * 255

    GetWindowText ActiveWindowHandle, Title, Len(Title)

    Me.Caption = Trim(Title)

    'example: if Me.Caption = "flower" then (end its process)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need the EXE filename in order to find & kill the process?

Comment: You have a window handle `ActiveWindowHandle` which is all you need to end the process. You don't need the exe name. There are different ways of ending processes from a window handle, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1378604/15639)

Comment: @DaveInCaz yes, because i want to terminate it from the root :D

Comment: @MarkJ very useful comment. i have tested the way. thank you for your time :)