# I want to write in NotePad from Textboxes value in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6

I want to write in Notepad. In Notepad, the first line should have two Heading Columns. First column's Name is "SNo" and Second Column's Name is "Patient's Names"

Now after opening the Visual Basic form, I will enter in Two textboxes named as SNo and Patient's Name. So these two values SNo and Patient's Name will be copied from textboxes and pasted in Notepad under the Headings SNo and Patient's Name respectively in Notepad.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into VB6's [SendKeys](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/57/sendkeys-command/) command.

```
Shell "notepad", vbNormalFocus
SendKeys "Sno,Patient's Name" & vbNewLine & SNo.Text & "," & PatientsName.Text
```

I have to question why you want to do this, though; it sounds like you're trying to write a comma delimited file (.csv) of sorts, and would be much better off using standard [File IO](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-121667.html), then using a [Shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290899/how-do-i-call-a-windows-shell-command-using-vb6) to open the file if you need it displayed in Notepad. Normally, using SendKeys is frowned upon as bad practice and insecure.

As a side note - please try to figure it out first, then come here with questions and everything you've tried so far. This will give us some idea as to what you're trying to do, and prevent you from claiming you have a Textbox named `Patient's Name`.

Comment: First of all, i Thank a lot for your guidance and co-operation. you asked a question why i am using notepad, Actually i am doing on line job data entry. i have to send my report in notepad but in specific format. And converting that data in specific format, it take lot of time, so i use programming to get my aim with in a minute than making it manually and waiting lot of time.

Comment: What do you mean you need to send your report in Notepad? Notepad is just an editor for text files, and those text files can be written by VB with simple file IO.