# VB6 + how to exe script on linux machine from VB6 app

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript, windows-xp

How can a VB6 application that runs on a Windows XP machine, run a script on a Linux machine (Redhat 5.3) via SSH?

VB application should take the following arguments

1. Linux login
2. Linux password
3. Script path

And then run the script path via SSH.

For example

```
ARG1 Login –        root
ARG2 Password –     USA123
ARG3 Script path -  /var/tmp/task.pl
```

VB6 will run the script `/var/tmp/task.pl` on the Linux machine.

Comment: @BNL hi I start to learn VB6 but I not found until now any example that explain how to run script from vb6 on Linux

Comment: How are you running VB 6 on a Linux machine?

Comment: @Cody Gray - no ,  I want to run VB6 on win XP and vb6 will ssh to linux machine in order to run there the script

Comment: @Cody Grayny -  Any suggestion for my question?

Comment: Just start `plink` from putty package (with VB6 `Shell` function) to execute any bash command via SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the "shell" function to create a command windows and then send ssh commands and parameters to it via the "sendKeys" function. However, this will be an error prone solution.

If you want a more permanent fix, take a look at [this VB Library for SSH manipulation](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/ssh/vb/). You may find it of use. Here is a link to [a sample project](ftp://ftp.activexperts-labs.com/samples/network-component/Visual%20Basic/Windows%20Applications/Demo/).

**EDIT:**

I don't have the VB6 IDE so I reused a VBScript file I had created earlier. It can either be run as is or can be very easily converted to VB6 code.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "o telnet.example.com"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(10000)
objShell.SendKeys "user"
WScript.Sleep(2000)
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "pass"
WScript.Sleep(2000)
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "./var/tmp/task.pl"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
```

Comment: Hi can you give me example of shell command that perform script execute on Linux from WIN XP shell

Comment: The "shell" function can be used to create a command prompt window which can then be manipulated to open a SSH session with the "sendkeys" function. Here's an SO post that shows it's use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290899/how-do-i-call-a-windows-shell-command-using-vb6. However, I suggest you take a look at my second suggestion. A solution based on "shell" and "sendkeys" can be quite unreliable.

Comment: `telnet.exe` doesn't do SSH.

Comment: @Deanna I have tried this with telnet.exe and I only wanted to post code that has definitely worked for me. However, the idea would work for any command line based ssh client (e.g. the ssh.exe that comes with OpenSSH).