# Activating Python Script on Raspberry Pi from VB.net Application on PC

Tags: python, vb.net, network-programming, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I have a simple python script on a Raspberry Pi connected using WiFi that activates an LED.  Simple enough.

Is it possible to launch that python script from another device attached to the same network using a simple button in VB.net?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use system call in VB, which run the following command in your PC:

```
 ssh user@rpi:/path/to/command.py arg1 arg2
```

see this, [How do I call a Windows shell command using VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290899/how-do-i-call-a-windows-shell-command-using-vb6).

You will need to run ssh server on the rpi, and possibly set passwordless ssh access using keys. 
For ssh on windows, you need either cygwin or putty.