# Running SQL Files with Variety of DDL commands and INSERT operations from a VB6 Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6, ado

I have a VB6 application, which restores a BAK file to the Database and runs through some scripts.

As there are large volume of SQL Scripts to run, I decided to move all in to a SQL File and then to run it from the Application.

The SQL File is now filled with lots of CREATE, UPDATE Table statements and also INSERT statements. I use both the SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.

Is there a way or function to execute the same from the VB6 code?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT 1**: The SQL File also have the CREATE Procedures and Triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run SQL scripts from the command line using

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx)

In VB6 you can execute command line strings using the Shell command, for example to start the Windows Calculator:

```
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\System32\calc.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

For more on the Shell command see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087.aspx and [How do I call a Windows shell command using VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290899/how-do-i-call-a-windows-shell-command-using-vb6)

The combination should give you what you need, like this:

```
Shell "sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql", vbNormalFocus
```

I see there is a good amount of useful information about SQLCMD in this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-sqlcmd-basics/ which may be a useful read.