# Command Line DIR to Excel Sheet by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, command, prompt

From excel VBA, how would I run the command prompt:

```
dir /a /s /b > FileList.xls
```

It should accept a directory variable from 'MSO Folder Picker', so that the user may select a directory to spill the contents onto a worksheet in the active workbook.

I have found several instances of VBA to execute similar functions, however, the command prompt outputs exactly the desired results. Rather elegantly, I might add.

Comment: Have a look at **Shell**. Should give you your answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290899/how-do-i-call-a-windows-shell-command-using-vb6 might help